# Locate and tag words in text file

Tags: c++

I need to read in a text file of 500 words or more(a real world article from newspaper, etc..) and locate and tag like this,  `<location> word <location/>`, and then print the entire article on the screen. Im using boost regex right now and its working ok. I want to try and use a list or array or some other data structure to have a list of the states and major cities, and search those and compare to the aticle. right now I'm using an array but I'm willing to use anything. Any ideas or clues?

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/regex.hpp>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
string cities[389];
string states [60];
string filename, line,city,state;
ifstream file,cityfile, statefile;
int i=0;
int j=0;
cityfile.open("c:\\cities.txt");
while (!cityfile.eof())
{

    getline(cityfile,city);
        cities[i]=city; 
        i++;
    //for (int i=0;i<500;i++)
        //file>>cities[i];
}
cityfile.close();

statefile.open("c:\\states.txt");
while (!statefile.eof())
{
    getline(statefile,state);
        states[j]=state; 
    //for (int i=0;i<500;i++)
    //cout<<states[j];
    j++;
}
statefile.close();
//4cout<<cities[4];






cout<<"Please enter the path and file name "<<endl;
cin>>filename;
file.open(filename);

while (!file.eof())
{
        while(getline(file, line)
        {


        }




        while(getline(file, line))
        {


        //string text = "Hello world";
        boost::regex re("[A-Z/]\.[A-Z\]\.|[A-Z/].*[:space:][A-Z/]|C........a");
        //boost::regex re(
        string fmt = "<locations>$&<locations\>";
        if(boost::regex_search(line, re))
            {
                 string result = boost::regex_replace(line, re, fmt);
                cout << result << endl;
            }
        /*else
            {
                cout << "Found Nothing" << endl;
            }*/

        }
}
file.close();

cin.get(),cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after asymptotic complexity - [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) offers a linear time complexity ( `O(n+m)`) (`n` and `m` are the lengths of the input strings). for searching a dictionary in a string.

An alternative is to put the tokenized words in a `map` (where the value is a list to the places in the stream of each string), and search for each string in the data in the tree. The complexity will be `O(|S| * (nlogn + mlogn) )` (`m` being the number of searched words, `n` is the number of words in the string, and `|S|` is the length of the average word)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any container that has a `.find()` method or supports `std::find()`. I'd use `set`, since `set::find()` runs in less than linear time.

Here is a program which does what you talk about. Note that the parsing doesn't work great, but that's not what I'm trying to demonstrate. You could continue to find the words using your parser, and use the call to `set::find()` to determine if they are locations.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

const std::set<std::string> locations { "Springfield", "Illinois", "Pennsylvania" };

int main () {
  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string word;
    while(iss >> word) {
      if(locations.find(word) == locations.end())
        std::cout << word << " ";
      else
        std::cout << "<location>" << word << "</location> ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm testing out the code you gave and >> and == have errors, and i've never used istringstream before, any ideas?

Comment: The example I gave [works for me](http://ideone.com/rIsMxk). My guess is you are missing an `#include`. What are the errors?

Comment: the red squiggly line is underneath >> and ==